# What is causing my @Html.DropDownList generate an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My registration get and post method was working without error and now it generates the following error after post:
[image]

Here is my [registration get and post](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c7f8ae86a144846bd5e41c39a7bd45fe)

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, please post errors as text and a minimal code snippet here. The error suggest you are using the wrong kind of parameter in the ViewData. Check this for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Because you return the view because `ModelState` is invalid but you did not populate the value of `ViewBag.Name` in the POST method (as your did in the GET method) so its `null` and

Comment: @Stefan I was trying to keep from posting too much code here. I wanted to show what was going on in the post and the get methods without making a the reader scroll to much

Comment: @Skullomania: I understand; but if you only post the relevant stuff, leaving out the authentication stuff for example, you'll get more points :-)